# unable to format time in am/pm in DataBinder.Eval

Tags: c#, datetime, repeater

i want to  display my time in 12:02 AM format

```
    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "departTime","{0:t}")%>
```

but above code doesn't work

Comment: "doesn't work" should be blocked by stackoverflow. Please specify what happened, do you get an exception or is the `DateTime` not formatted?

Comment: Date time not formatted .. it shows 12:02:00

Comment: But it _is_ a `DateTime` and not a `String`?

Comment: You'll have to show us what the definition of `departTime` looks like.  I tested with it as a `DateTime` property, and your own code and every answer in this post all work just fine.  My guess is the same as Tim's in that you are probably passing it as a string.

Comment: in database table departTime is as time(7) that is timespan

Answer (score 1):

Using a label to convert a string to a short time with AM/PM

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTripTime" runat="server" Text='<%# (DateTime.Parse(Eval("TripTime").ToString()).ToShortTimeString()) %>'></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
 <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "departTime",@"{0:h\:mm tt}")%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "tt". You can try with <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "departTime","{0:hh:mm:ss tt}")%>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%# (Eval("departTime") != null ? Eval("departTime","{0:HH:mm:ss tt}") : "unavailible") %>
```